# Should the TITLE attribute be on images or parent links for SEO?

Tags: html, seo, title, alt

When it comes to linked images and SEO, should the `title` attribute be used on the `<img>` tag, the parent `<a>` tag or both?

Common practice seems to be to add the `title` attribute to the `<a>` tag. But is this best for SEO? Would there be any harm in adding it to both tags? If not, is there harm in the `title` text being identical on both?

P.S. I am aware that you should almost always use the `alt` attribute on `<img>` tags regardless of the `title` attribute.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: I was primarily curious about the use of the `title` attribute and where it is the most proper place to use it since it can technically be used both places. And because the `title` attribute is used a lot for SEO, it seemed like the right direction for the question. A moderator can feel free to close this if needed. Apologies for the trouble, I'm still a newbie when it comes to asking questions here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

w3schools defines the title attribute as follows:

> The title attribute specifies extra information about an element.
>   The information is most often shown as a tooltip text when the mouse moves over the element.

As for semantic markup it's enough to add the `title` attribute to the `a` tag. Adding it to the image within isn't necessary, except you want to have different content for the title attribute to describe directly the image.

As far as SEO is concerned: if the `img` tag already has the `alt` attribute, you don't need the title attribute.

A Usefull blogentry about that:
http://www.wpromote.com/blog/seo/image-alt-vs-title-using-alt-title-attributes-in-image-tags/

Excerpt:

> While the ALT attribute provides alternative text when images cannot
>   be displayed, the TITLE text offers supplementary information about
>   the element in which it is contained. According to this post on the
>   Google Webmaster Blog, **Google tends to focus on the information in the ALT text. So there you have it! If you’re only going to use one attribute… ALT it is**!

Comment: Very useful blog entry, thank you. It nicely puts into context what kind of text you should use in the `alt` and `title` attributes. I still wonder though, if you're still going to use `title`, should it be on the `<img>` or `<a>` tag?

Comment: @sarahjadesigns i would give the `<a>` tag the `title` attribute and the `<img>` just the `alt` attribute.

Comment: @sarahjadesigns, if my answer helped with your problem, could you please mark my Answer as the solution so i get the rep points? (:

Comment: Sorry @LeaveAirykson, I re-read this now and I'm not sure why I never marked this.

Comment: no problem, thx for doing it now (:

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question.
The title attribute **isn't used** by Google and Bing (in search engine ranking algorithm). Titles attributes are **useful for accessibility** (blind people and vocal navigation for example).

Nevertheless, the useful (**very useful** in SEO strategy) is the "**alt**" attribute. This one is used by Google and other search engines. **"alt" has to be used on img balise.**

Comment: I would have agreed with you, like 2 years ago. On the last QCon, nearly all SEO´s  have pointed out the importance of the title tag. You can run a simple test. Add an image to your site, add a strange title like dsfevervdsfvrevfdvre to it, wait till google robot indexes your site, and you will see the engine cares about it. Also it is important for the Google Image search, but explaining the context between Google Image search and the normal search, would lead too far, hence its only a comment

Comment: @CodeFanatic I'm very interested about the title attribute having effects on SEO but haven't found any source, do you have one where I could read more about it???

Answer (score -1):

In the `<alt>` attribute you describe, what you can see on the image.

In  the `<title>` attribute of the image, you describe the general topic, the image is about.

In the `<title>` attribute of the `<a>`, you describe the general topic, the `<a>` is about.

If there is nothing else in your `<a>` than the image, there is no need to add a `<title>` attribute to the image (talking about the Google Robot), else it is.

Conclusion: Do never use identical titles, that is absolutely useless for Search Engines, and will

1. brings your Code Quality in there ranking down
2. not generate new keywords

EDIT1: I am not agreeing that much, with the other answers, since the title attributeis at least used in the Google Image Crawling and for checking the Code Quality, which can both decrease your CPC (=Cost per Clicks) when using adwords

Comment: They are not tags. They are attributes.