# Reasons to Use the Title Attribute in HTML Tags

Tags: html, title

> NOTE: I *don't* mean `<title></title`, I mean `<div title=""></div>`. Just wanted to get that obviousness out of the way to people who scan questions without reading.

I have read a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868341/what-is-the-use-of-the-title-attribute-on-a-html-element) of [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382768/accessibility-of-the-title-attribute) on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931640/should-the-title-attribute-be-on-images-or-parent-links-for-seo) that describe the purpose of the title tag, what it should be used for, and so on and so forth. Can someone please explain to me if these are appropriate reasons for title tags:

- Use for blind people that have programs that read text (***Would this be important for images that take the place of third-party links? Or is the alt attribute better?***)
- Lazy way to use a simple tooltip

---

I learned HTML when HTML5 was brand new a few years ago, and teachers that explained HTML5 didn't even bother touching on such archaic things as the title attribute.

Basically, is the purpose of the title attribute even *useful* in modern-day HTML5? Are the "examples" I listed above even relevant anymore?

Comment: It's not a required attribute, if you're doing it because you care about accessibility try it in JAWS and see if it does what you think/want?

Comment: Test the page and check how google sees your title https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/